# How To Projection To List using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, repository, automapper

I have dto like this:

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItemDTO> OrderItems
}

public class OrderItemDTO
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

When I projection the `Order` entity to `OrderDTO` using AutoMapper

```
return context.Orders
    .Include(o => o.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.Item))
    .Where(o => o.OrderID == orderID)
    .Project().To<OrderDTO>()
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

I'm getting the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DTO.OrderItemDTO] 
>   ToList[OrderItemDTO](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DTO.OrderItemDTO])'
>   method,  and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is my mapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemDTO>();
```

If I change `List<OrderItemDTO>` to `IEnumerable<OrderItemDTO>`, it works, but I need in `List<OrderItemDTO>` to manipulate the contents of list.

Is there any way how to solve this?

Comment: Which version of auto mapper you are using ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh I'm using Automapper 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated that you are using AutoMapper 3.3.1 - this version was released over 2 years ago and there have been many improvements (especially around LINQ projections) since then.

I would recommend updating your AutoMapper and seeing if the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the automapper and related library. It works